Google Maps API: google.maps.Map is not a constructor error
I have a page where Google Maps is loaded, was working correctly. Recently (few days ago) it starting throwing errors at DEV environment. At first with CTRL+F5 this issue would disappear, but now is constantly occurring. I've searched for any HTML or JS change into my code that may have caused this, could find any changes. I've checked at production enviroment and this issue occurs there too (with older code), therefore this seems to be some external interference.
I've tried to change the script source to older versions (v=3.56 and v=3.55) but issue remains. Current version is 3.57.8b.
I didn't find any issue at billing side either.
JS is twrowing first a warning and then an error, see below. Has anyone faced this? Any ideas on how to solve this?
Console:
jQuery.Deferred exception: google.maps.Map is not a constructor TypeError: google.maps.Map is not a constructor at initMap

Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.Map is not a constructor at initMap

Script
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&loading=async&libraries=places&language=XXXX&libraries=marker"></script>

JS Code:
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: { lat: 10, lng: 10 },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapId: 'Customers',
    });
    //Additional code
}


We also had this issue a few days ago, what we did was remove loading=async and it works fine

it appears a similar issue has been reported here. Could you please star the issue and if possible, provide more information? Thanks

Thanks for the clarification. Since this was the second error in a 15 days windows, we looked for alternatives and we are currently happy with Mapbox software. We had to find a fast solution to this since we were about to start participating in a business event, as exhibitors.
